# Recvall with while loop doesn't work between two devices in python

Tags: python, string, sockets, while-loop, server

I have the following problem: I want a sever to send the contents of a textfile
when requested to do so. I have writen a server script which sends the contents to the client and the client script which receives all the contents with a revcall loop. The recvall works fine when
I run the server and client from the same device for testing.
But when I run the server from a different device in the same wifi network to receive the textfile contents from the server device, the recvall doesn't work and I only receive the first 1460 bytes of the text.

## server script

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("", 5000))
server.listen(5)


def send_file(client):
    read_string = open("textfile", "rb").read()  #6 kilobyte large textfile
    client.send(read_string)


while True:
    client, data = server.accept()
    connect_data = client.recv(1024)
    if connect_data == b"send_string":
        send_file(client)
    else:
        pass
```

## client script

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("192.168.1.10", 5000))

connect_message = client.send(b"send_string")

receive_data = ""
while True:                                        # the recvall loop
    receive_data_part = client.recv(1024).decode()
    receive_data += receive_data_part
    if len(receive_data_part) < 1024:
        break

print(receive_data)
```

Comment: You should use `.sendall()` instead of `.send()`, especially when sending a large amount of data.  The alternative is to check the return value of `.send()`, and retry if the entire string wasn't handled.

Comment: You can receive anything from 1 to 1024 bytes. Between machines your data is being segmented a bit differently and you receive partial < 1024 buffers. This is normal for a streaming protocol.

Comment: Your protocol needs some way of letting the receiver know when a transmission is complete. This could be closing the socket, sending a total length value before the data, or some sort of end sentinal such as a NULL value. (http uses two newlines in a row for instance). There are lots of ways to solve this problem.

Comment: BTW, the server has the same problem. There is no guarantee that you'll receive exactly a `b"send_string"` in a single recv buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv(1024)` means to receive at least 1 and at most 1024 bytes. If the connection has closed, you receive 0 bytes, and if something goes wrong, you get an exception.

TCP is a stream of bytes. It doesn't try to keep the bytes from any given `send` together for the `recv`. When you make the call, if the TCP endpoint has some data, you get that data.

In client, you assume that anything less than 1024 bytes must be the last bit of data. Not so. You can receive partial buffers at any time. Its a bit subtle on the server side, but you make the same mistake there by assuming that you'll receive exactly the command `b"send_string"` in a single call.

You need some sort of a protocol that tells receivers when they've gotten the right amount of data for an action. There are many ways to do this, so I can't really give you *the* answer. But this is why there are protocols out there like zeromq, xmlrpc, http, etc...